# What does "Your supreme selfishness is our gain" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Here is a quote from 127 Hours, 2010 film.

> **Aron** : Can I say a big hi to Mom and Dad in Englewood, Colorado?
>
> **The Host** : Mom and Dad! Never forget Mom and Dad. Right, Aron?
>
> **ARON** : Umm. Yeah. Sorry I didn’t pick up the other night, Mom. I would have told
> you where I was going and well- wouldn’t be stuck here now, would I?
>
> **The Host** : Well, I always like to say, your supreme selfishness is our
> gain, Aron. Anyone else you’d like to say hi to?

He said "your supreme selfishness is our gain". Does it can mean "your supreme selfishness would augment our talk show program's viewer ratings."?

I searched dictionary on "gain" as noun. It can refer to "profit" as well as, right?
Please confrim whether I was correct or not. Please help me understand! (◕_◕)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, "(X) is our gain" means "We benefit as a result of (X)", whatever X may be.

In your example, the Host is saying that as a result of Aron's supreme selfishness, the show that the Host is hosting is getting additional popularity and ratings.  It's not the selfishness itself directly, but the actions and consequences of that selfishness that created a situation from which the show derived its benefit.